# Using math.div instead of / in scss

Tags: sass

Need to rewrite this function using math.div instead of slash.
Details mentioned in the URL given below.

https://jsfiddle.net/26ty5aj7

```
    @function px2em($px, $metric: 'em', $base-font-size: 16px) {
      @if unitless($px) {
        @warn "Assuming #{$px} to be in pixels, attempting to convert it into pixels.";
        @return px2em($px * 1px, $metric, $base-font-size);
      } @else if unit($px) == em {
        @return $px;
      }  
      @return #{($px / $base-font-size) + $metric};
    }
    
    // Pixels to rem based on sass-mq
    @function px2rem($px) {
      @if unit($px) == rem {
        @return $px;
      }

      @return px2em($px, 'rem');
    }
```

**`@return #{($px / $base-font-size) + $metric};`**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are your functions with the updated syntax. Make sure to keep the `@use` import at the top of your file.

```css
@use "sass:math";

@function px2em($px, $metric: 'em', $base-font-size: 16px) {
  @if unitless($px) {
    @warn "Assuming #{$px} to be in pixels, attempting to convert it into pixels.";
    @return px2em($px * 1px, $metric, $base-font-size);
  } @else if unit($px) == em {
    @return $px;
  }
  $test: #{math.div($px, $base-font-size) + $metric};
  @return $test;
}

// Pixels to rem based on sass-mq
@function px2rem($px) {
  @if unit($px) == rem {
    @return $px;
  }

  @return px2em($px, 'rem');
}
```

### Automated Migration

If you have many instances of division, you may want to take a look at the [automatic migration tool provided by Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div#automatic-migration), as thoughtfully pointed out by @Andreas in the comments.

```sh
# Install the tool globally using npm
npm install -g sass-migrator
# Run the codemod on all .scss files recursively from the working directory
sass-migrator division **/*.scss

# OR

# Use npx to install temporarily and immediately run (similar to above)
npx --yes sass-migrator division **/*.scss
```

### Compatibility

Keep in mind that the deprecation is a transition, and [`math.div` is currently only supported in Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#div) ([`sass` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)) >=1.33.0 and not supported in Ruby Sass or LibSass ([`node-sass` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)).

This means it is safe to update when your Sass files are only compiled in your project. However, maintainers of libraries that export Sass, like Bootstrap for example, should be mindful as it could be a breaking change.

Comment: sass compatibility to use math.div is since "sass": "^1.33"

Comment: from the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div#automatic-migration), there is also an automatic migration tool: `npm install -g sass-migrator` and then `sass-migrator division **/*.scss`
`

Comment: note, if you don't or for some reason cannot use `math.div` there are a couple of tricks to divide by simple numbers like `$x / 2` simply use `$x * 0.5`. for complex cases you will need to call the function and you will need to make the upgrade