# Ratio of two variables in Sass

Tags: sass

I am trying to scale a value based on the ratio of two variables:

```
$w: 500px;
$a: 1px;
$b: 2px;
$result: calc(#{$w} * #{$a}/#{$b});
```

I tried doing `calc(#{$w} * math.div(#{$a},#{$b}));` instead. To my surprise, I could not find any previous post on the topic.

So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: The correct way to divide depends on your version and implementation (DartSass, LibSass, RubySass) of sass https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using math.div instead of / in scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688301/using-math-div-instead-of-in-scss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `calc` to assign sass variables. It is a css function that is evaluated during runtime, sass is processed during compile-time.

Here are your options:

```
@use "sass:math";

$w: 500px;
$a: 1;
$b: 2;
$ratio: math.div($a, $b);
$result: $w * $ratio;
```

or in older sass versions

```
$w: 500px;
$a: 1;
$b: 2;
$result: $w * ($a / $b);
```

Comment: Using ScSS. In CodePen, the first option did not work, but the second did! If one can write calculations like this, what did they introduce `calc` for?

Comment: As far as I can tell currently the implementations differ quite substantially: DartSass uses the new `math.div` and the new calculation functions `calc`, `clamp()`, `min()`, and `max()` as [documented here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/calculations) and LibSass still uses the old syntax.